# How to create a SqlAlchemy class attribute from a calculated field in SQL query?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, postgis, fastapi, pydantic

### Problem

I am trying to create an API using the FastAPI framework that allow to get data from a PostgreSQL / PostGIS database. I have followed the FastAPI SQL [tutorial](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/sql-databases/) and have managed until now to create the basic structure.

However, I am now facing a problem that I didn't manage to solve : I would like to provide through a route the basic info about an object, including its geographic ones (geometry and area for now).

I managed to get the geometry with GeoAlchemy and parse it to pydantic validators with a custom function.  But I didn't find any way to parse the area, that must be calculated through postgresql query as it is tied to a  specific PostGIS function.

My first try was to add the function to the query in the crud file. But it doesn't work. It seems like the query function return two objects that the pydantic validator does not recognize. I've tried to find other possibilities on internet, but the solutions provided (hybrid_property, column_property) works mainly with simple data type that allows to create a "calculated" attribute within the python code.

Have you idea how I could bypass this problem ? Thank you for your help

### Here is the code of my initial try

***database.py***

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

RAW_DB_CONNECTION = "**************"

engine = create_engine(RAW_DB_CONNECTION)

SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

Base = declarative_base()
```

***crud.py***

```
from sqlalchemy import func
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from . import models, schemas


def parcelle_get_basic_info(db: Session, id: str):
    return db.query(
        models.Parcelle,
        func.ST_Area(func.ST_Transform(models.Parcelle.geom, 2154)).label('area')
        ).filter(
            models.Parcelle.id == id
        ).first()
```

***models.py***

```
from sqlalchemy import Boolean, Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String, select, func
from geoalchemy2 import Geometry
from sqlalchemy.orm import query_expression
from sqlalchemy.sql import literal

from .database import Base

class Parcelle(Base):
    __tablename__= "_limites_parcelle_cadastre"
    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'admin'}

    id = Column(String, primary_key=True, index=True)
    commune = Column(String)
    geom = Column(Geometry(geometry_type='MULTIPOLYGON', srid=4326))
    area = Column(Float)
```

***schemas.py***

```
from typing import List, Optional
from geoalchemy2.shape import to_shape 
from geoalchemy2.elements import WKBElement
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator

def ewkb_to_wkt(geom: WKBElement):
    """
    Converts a geometry formated as WKBE to WKT 
    in order to parse it into pydantic Model

    Args:
        geom (WKBElement): A geometry from GeoAlchemy query
    """
    return to_shape(geom).wkt

class ItemBase(BaseModel):
    id: str
    commune: str
    geom : str
    area : Optional[float]

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
    
    @validator('geom', pre=True,allow_reuse=True,whole=True, always=True)
    def correct_geom_format(cls, v):
        if not isinstance(v, WKBElement):
            raise ValueError('must be a valid WKBE element')
        return ewkb_to_wkt(v)
```

***main.py***

```
from typing import List

from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI, HTTPException
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

from . import crud, models, schemas
from .database import SessionLocal, engine

models.Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

app = FastAPI()


# Dependency
def get_db():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()

@app.get("/parcelle/{parcelle_id}", response_model=schemas.ItemBase)
def get_parcelle_info(parcelle_id: str, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    parcelle_info = crud.parcelle_get_basic_info(db, id=parcelle_id)
    if parcelle_info is None:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="Parcelle not found")
    return parcelle_info
```

### And the error I get

```
127.0.0.1:59404 - "GET /parcelle/33449000CE0006 HTTP/1.1" 500 Internal Server Error
ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/upfactor/code/api/info/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/h11_impl.py", line 394, in run_asgi
    result = await app(self.scope, self.receive, self.send)
  File "/upfactor/code/api/info/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 45, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/upfactor/code/api/info/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 199, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "/upfactor/code/api/info/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 111, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "/upfactor/code/api/info/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 181, in __call__
    raise exc from None
  File "/upfactor/code/api/info/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 159, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "/upfactor/code/api/info/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 82, in __call__
    raise exc from None
  File "/upfactor/code/api/info/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 71, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "/upfactor/code/api/info/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 566, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "/upfactor/code/api/info/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 227, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/upfactor/code/api/info/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 41, in app
    response = await func(request)
  File "/upfactor/code/api/info/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 209, in app
    response_data = await serialize_response(
  File "/upfactor/code/api/info/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 126, in serialize_response
    raise ValidationError(errors, field.type_)
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 3 validation errors for ItemBase
response -> id
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
response -> commune
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
response -> geom
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
```

Comment: What happens if you return `ItemBase.from_orm(query)` in `parcelle_get_basic_info` where `query = db.query(
        models.Parcelle,
        func.ST_Area(func.ST_Transform(models.Parcelle.geom, 2154)).label('area')
        ).filter(
            models.Parcelle.id == id
        ).first()
`

Comment: Same error unfortunately...